# What is the meaning of Powershell's Copy-Item's -container argument?

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am writing a script for MS PowerShell.  This script uses the `Copy-Item` command.  One of the optional arguments to this command is "`-container`". The documentation for the argument states that specifying this argument "Preserves container objects during the copy operation."

This is all well and good, for I would be the last person to want unpreserved container objects during a copy operation.  But in all seriousness, what does this argument do?  Particularly in the case where I am copying a disk directory tree from one place to another, what difference does this make to the behavior of the `Copy-Item` command?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The container the documentation is talking about is the folder structure.  If you are doing a recursive copy and want to preserve the folder structure, you would use the -container switch. (Note: by default the -container switch is set to true, so you really would not need to specify it.  If you wanted to turn it off you could use `-container: $false`.)

There is a catch to this... if you do a directory listing and pipe it to Copy-Item, it will not preserve the folder structure.  If you want to preserve the folder structure, you have to specify the -path property and the -recurse switch.

Answer (score 80):

I too found the documentation less than helpful. I did some tests to see how the `-Container` parameter works in conjunction with `-Recurse` when copying files and folders.

Note that `-Container` means `-Container: $true`.

This is the file structure I used for the examples:

```
#    X:.
#    ├───destination
#    └───source
#        │   source.1.txt
#        │   source.2.txt
#        │
#        └───source.1
#                source.1.1.txt
```

- For all examples, the current location (pwd) is `X:\`.
- I used PowerShell 4.0.

---

1) To copy just the source folder (empty folder):

```
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination -Container
#    X:.
#    ├───destination
#    │   └───source
#    └───source (...)
```

*The following gives an error:*

```
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination -Container: $false
# Exception: Container cannot be copied to another container. 
#            The -Recurse or -Container parameter is not specified.
```

2) To copy the whole folder structure with files:

```
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination -Recurse
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination -Recurse -Container
#    X:.
#    ├───destination
#    │   └───source
#    │       │   source.1.txt
#    │       │   source.2.txt
#    │       │
#    │       └───source.1
#    │               source.1.1.txt
#    └───source (...)
```

3) To copy all descendants (files and folders) into a single folder:

```
Copy-Item -Path source -Destination .\destination -Recurse -Container: $false
#    X:.
#    ├───destination
#    │   │   source.1.1.txt
#    │   │   source.1.txt
#    │   │   source.2.txt
#    │   │
#    │   └───source.1
#    └───source (...)
```

Comment: This answer deserves more votes. It leaves nothing to imagination. +1