# Powershell Copy Files with a Blacklist (Exclude) and a Whitelist (Include)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm translating some msbuild scripts to powershell.

In msbuild, I can generate a blacklist and/or whitelist of files I want to (recursively) copy to a destination folder.

As seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
        <WindowsSystem32Directory>c:\windows\System32</WindowsSystem32Directory>
        <ArtifactDestinationFolder>$(WorkingCheckout)\ZZZArtifacts</ArtifactDestinationFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">

        <CallTarget Targets="CleanArtifactFolder" />
        <CallTarget Targets="CopyFilesToArtifactFolder" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CleanArtifactFolder">

        <RemoveDir Directories="$(ArtifactDestinationFolder)" Condition="Exists($(ArtifactDestinationFolder))"/>
        <MakeDir Directories="$(ArtifactDestinationFolder)" Condition="!Exists($(ArtifactDestinationFolder))"/>
        <Message Text="Cleaning done" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyFilesToArtifactFolder">

        <ItemGroup>
            <MyExcludeFiles Include="$(WindowsSystem32Directory)\**\EventViewer_EventDetails.xsl" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WindowsSystem32Directory)\**\*.xsl" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)"/>
            <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WindowsSystem32Directory)\**\*.xslt" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)"/>
            <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WindowsSystem32Directory)\**\*.png" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)"/>
            <MyIncludeFiles Include="$(WindowsSystem32Directory)\**\*.jpg" Exclude="@(MyExcludeFiles)"/>            
        </ItemGroup>        

        <Copy
                SourceFiles="@(MyIncludeFiles)"
                DestinationFiles="@(MyIncludeFiles->'$(ArtifactDestinationFolder)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        />

        </Target>

    </Project>
```

**Can I do the same in powershell?**

I have tried the below, but it creates a file called "C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults"
(its a file with no extension, not a directory)

```
$sourceDirectory = 'c:\windows\System32\*'
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults'
$excludeFiles = @('EventViewer_EventDetails.xsl')
$includeFiles = @('*.xsl','*.xslt','*.png','*.jpg')


Copy-Item $sourceDirectory $destinationDirectory -Recurse -Include $includeFiles -Exclude $excludeFiles
# -Container:$false
```

APPEND:

I tried this:

```
$sourceDirectory = 'c:\windows\System32'
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults'
$excludeFiles = @('EventViewer_EventDetails.xsl')
$includeFiles = @('*.xsl','*.xslt','*.png','*.jpg')


Copy-Item $sourceDirectory $destinationDirectory -Recurse -Include $includeFiles -Exclude $excludeFiles
```

(No results, not even a file with no extension)

and I tried this:

```
$sourceDirectory = 'c:\windows\System32'
$destinationDirectory = 'C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults'
$excludeFiles = @('EventViewer_EventDetails.xsl')
$includeFiles = @('*.xsl','*.xslt','*.png','*.jpg')


Copy-Item $sourceDirectory $destinationDirectory -Recurse -Include $includeFiles -Exclude $excludeFiles -Container:$false
```

(No results, not even a file with no extension)

Comment: I think I would probably use robocopy.

Comment: I had the same result with @mklement's suggestion, I think your original script fails because the parameter at position 2 (-destination) will be used to rename on the copy thus overwriting the static name. ( I tried with an appended `-whatif`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Copy-Item -Recurse`**, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0, has its **quirks and limitations**; here's what I found:

<sup>If you have additional information or corrections, please let us know.</sup>

There are two **fundamental *ways to call* `Copy-Item -Recurse`**:

- (a) specifying a *directory path* as the source - `c:\windows\system32`
- (b) using a *wildcard expression* as the source that resolves to multiple items *in* the source directory  - `c:\windows\system32\*`

There are two **fundamental *problems***:

- The copying **behavior *varies* based on whether the *target directory already exists*** - see below.
- The **`-Include` parameter does not work** properly and neither does `-Exclude`, though problems are much more likely to arise with `-Include`; see [GitHub issue #8459](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8459).

**DO NOT USE THE SOLUTIONS BELOW IF YOU NEED TO USE `-Include`** - if you do need `-Include`, use [LotPing's helpful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819214/45375).

---

#### Case (a) - a single directory path as the source

If the source is a single directory (or is the only directory among the items that a wildcard pattern resolved to), `Copy-Item` implicitly also interprets the *destination* as a directory.

However, **if the destination directory *already exists*, the copied items will be placed in a *subdirectory* named for the *source* directory**, which in your case means: `C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults\System32`

[GitHub issue #2934](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2934) that - rightfully - complains about this counter-intuitive behavior

There are two basic **workarounds**:

**If acceptable, *remove the destination directory first*, if it exists - which is obviously to be done with CAUTION** (remove `-WhatIf` once you're confident that the command works as intended):

```
# Remove a pre-existing destination directory:
if (Test-Path $destinationDirectory) {
  Remove-Item $destinationDirectory -Recurse -WhatIf
}

# Now Copy-Item -Recurse works as intended.
# As stated, -Exclude works as intended, but -Include does NOT.
Copy-Item $sourceDirectory $destinationDirectory -Recurse
```

*Caveat*: `Remove-Item -Recurse`, regrettably, can intermittently act asynchronously and can even fail - for a robust alternative, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53561052/45375).

**If you want to *retain* a *preexisting* destination dir.** - e.g., if you want to *add to* contents of the destination directory,

- Create the target dir. on demand; that is, create it only if it doesn't already exist.
- Use `Copy-Item` to copy the *contents* of the source directory to the target dir.

```
# Ensure that the target dir. exists.
# -Force is a quiet no-op, if it already exists.
$null = New-Item -Force -ItemType Directory -LiteralPath $destinationDirectory

# Copy the *contents* of the source directory to the target, using
# a wildcard.
# -Force ensures that *hidden items*, if any, are included too.
# As stated, -Exclude works as intended, but -Include does NOT.
Copy-Item -Force $sourceDirectory/* $destinationDirectory -Recurse
```

---

#### Case (b) - a wildcard expression as the source

Note:

- If there's **exactly *1* directory among the resolved items**, the same rules as in **case (a)** apply.
- Otherwise, the **behavior is only problematic if the *target item doesn't exist yet*.** - see below.
- Therefore, the **workaround** is to **ensure *beforehand* that the destination directory exists**:
  `New-Item -Force -Path $destinationDirectory -ItemType Directory`

**If the target item (`-Destination` argument) doesn't exist yet**:

- If there are ***multiple directories* among the resolved items**, `Copy-Item` copies the *first* directory, and then **fails** on the second with the following error message:
  `Container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item`
- **If the source is a single file or resolves to *files only***, `Copy-Item` implicitly **interprets a non-existent destination as a *file***.
  With multiple files, this means that **a *single* destination file is created**, whose content is the content of the file that happened to be copied *last* - i.e, there is **data loss**.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains the voodoo in good detail.  And I think the other guys "touch" method does what you say as "ensure beforehand that the destination directory exists:".    Seems like alot of drama for a recursive item-copy.  Of course the destination folders are not going to be there.....that's why I'm copying them.

Comment: @granadaCoder: Thanks. It turns out that `Copy-Item` is even more badly broken than I thought - `-Include` (unlike `-Exclude`) doesn't work as expected - see my update.

Comment: Dude, you are a "Copy-Item" guru/genius!  You've forgotten more about Copy-Item then I'll ever know.  SOF person of the day!

Comment: @granadaCoder: Thanks. It is unfortunate that such a fundamental cmdlet has so many "quirks". Let's hope they get fixed in v6.

Comment: Exactly, today in agile-stand-up, I have to tell everybody I spent almost a day on "file-copy".  I can't wait for the laughter.  At least I have this question as a "proof text" !

Answer (score 3):

Using a suggestion I found from here (the "touch" approach)

[Should Copy-Item create the destination directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523497/should-copy-item-create-the-destination-directory-structure/7523632#7523632)

I got the below to work.

I'll leave this question as "Unanswered" for a few days, maybe somebody has something better.  The New-Item seems weird to me, since the Copy-Item should not fluke-out in an Include and Exclude list IMHO.

(use variable setters as per the original question)

```
IF (Test-Path -Path $destinationDirectory -PathType Container) 
{ 
    Write-Host "$destinationDirectory already exists" -ForegroundColor Red
} 
ELSE 
{ 
    New-Item -Path $destinationDirectory -ItemType directory 
} 


# the two scripts below are same except for "New-Item" vs "Copy-Item" , thus the "New-Item" trick-it-to-work voodoo

Get-ChildItem $sourceDirectory -Include $includeFiles -Exclude $excludeFiles -Recurse -Force |
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path  {
        Join-Path $destinationDirectory $_.FullName.Substring($sourceDirectory.Length)
    }  -Force

Get-ChildItem $sourceDirectory -Include $includeFiles -Exclude $excludeFiles -Recurse -Force |
    Copy-Item -Destination {
        Join-Path $destinationDirectory $_.FullName.Substring($sourceDirectory.Length)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To keep an overview I shortened your vars (and changed dst to fit my env)

```
$src = 'c:\windows\System32'
$dst = 'Q:\Test\2017-03\15\PowershellResults'
$exc = @('EventViewer_EventDetails.xsl')
$inc = @('*.xsl','*.xslt','*.png','*.jpg')

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Rec -Inc $inc -Exc $exc -ea silentlycontinue|ForEach{
  $DestPath = $_.DirectoryName -replace [regex]::escape($src),$dst
  If (!(Test-Path $DestPath)){MkDir $DestPath}
  $_|Copy-Item -Destination $DestPath -Force
}
```

**Edit** Essentially the same as your example, maybe a bit denser

Comment: When I use the -whatif, the output is beautiful, and I see the correct source and destination names.  When I remove the -whatif, I get  ::::::::    Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\work9\MsBuildExamples\FileCopyRecursive\PowershellResults\DriverStore\FileRepository\synpd.inf_amd64_5f3e8d89f52f304c\TP4-I.JPG'.    where the original filename was "c:\windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\synpd.inf_amd64_5f3e8d89f52f304c\TP4-I.JPG"  This is why I think the guy came up with the "touch" method I describe in my method.

Comment: Edited the script above, does a mkdir if the destination path doesn't exist.

Comment: I see now.  The other guy is "touch"ing it, so it makes the directory(ies), while you are string manipulating and manually creating the directory(ies) if they don't exist.  Then the Copy-Item ends up working.  Zam.  A lot of drama for a simple file copy task.