# Powershell is copying a folder's contents, but neglecting to copy the folder

Tags: powershell

I have a file structure similar to:

OldLocation/A, OldLocation/B, OldLocation/C, and OldLocation/D

I want to move folders A, B, and D to NewLocation (along with their contents). I have the following code:

```
    $Copyfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory -Exclude 'C'



foreach ($item in $Copyfiles)
{

Copy-Item -Path $item -Recurse -Force -Destination $Dest
}
```

My desired goal is to end up with NewLocation/A/A's stuff, NewLocation/B/B's stuff, NewLocation/D/D's stuff

It seems to almost work, the only hang up is for some reason it only copies the contents of folder A, and not the folder itself. Thus I get NewLoacation/A's stuff, NewLocation/B/B's stuff, and NewLocation/D/D's stuff

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` gets the content of the folder, not the folder itself. Is this what you mean? Can you post your actual code? It doesn't look like `$Dest` is changing so I assume you could just do `Copy-Item -Path $folder -Recurse -Force -Destination $Dest
}`

Comment: @NekoMusume: `-Directory` makes `Get-ChildItem` get directories (folders) themselves.

Comment: @mklement0 So where is the `Get-ChildItem` taking place? `\Oldlocation`? In that case why do you need `-recurse`? Are they all going to the same destination? And why are they excluding `C`?

Comment: Oops, I'm just an idiot... I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make sure that the destination directory exists *beforehand*,** because [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item) behaves differently when copying *whole directories*, depending on whether the destination directory already exists or not:

- If it *doesn't* exist, the source directory's *contents* are copied to the created-on-demand destination directory.
- If it *does* exist, the source directory *as a whole* is copied to the  destination directory *as a subdirectory*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818635/45375) for background information.

---

You can use the following command to ensure that destination directory `$Dest` exists, using [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-Item)'s  `-Force` switch for *desired-state* logic: it will create the destination directory *on demand* (and return a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance describing either the newly created or the preexisting directory).

```
$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force $Dest
```

Comment: @Andy: Yes, though I suggest adding `-Force` for desired-state logic: it'll create the destination dir. _on demand_ - please see my update.