# How to specify multiple file types to exclude when deleting files in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the below script to copy files from an install directory, and then remove all files except XML files. I'd like to also exclude `.log` and `.txt` files from deletion. How do I format this to accomplish that?

Bonus points if there is a way to download ONLY XML/LOG/TXT files, including the folder structure, without having to go back and delete extra stuff.

```
Copy-Item -Path $cis_wild -Destination $target_cis -Container -Recurse
Get-ChildItem -Path $target_cis -Recurse -File | Where {($_.Extension -ne ".xml")} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: [1] if the `-Exclude` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` was reliable, i would say to use that. it aint, tho. ///// [2] instead, use a regex OR pattern of your extensions to filter the files.

Comment: I agree, `-Exclude` and `-Include` scare me :( I would rather use a manual approach

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, the rule of thumb is: _with `-Recurse`_, `-Exclude` and `-Include` work as expected (I know it isn't easy to remember these subtleties).

Comment: @mklement0 - from my direct experience ... the `-Recurse` is needed ... but the code is still flaky. i have had it get only SOME of the targets - and that aint acceptable. i finally decided that - since both `-Include` and `-Exclude` are run after the filesystem returns things to the cmdlet - i would use `ForEach-Object` and save me the pain of wondering if it wold fail this time. [*sigh ...*] it aint an all-up `filter left`, but it works every time. [*grin*]

Comment: again, agree with Lee hehe, would trust more my own code than having to remember when the params are _supposed to work_ and even then wonder if they will work.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, that's understandable - it is annoying that you can't just rely on these parameters to work consistently. Yes, filtering happens after the fact, but the aspect of using just a parameter on the original cmdlet vs. having to filter via `ForEach-Object` in a separate pipeline segment is still appealing. I'm not aware of any cases where combination with `-Recurse` fails - if you can summarize succinctly the pattern of when it does, please do. Additionally - assuming PowerShell (Core) is still affected - I encourage you to file a bug report.

Comment: @mklement0 - i never was able to nail it down. [*blush*] what seemed to be the same situation would _sometimes_ ignore those two parameters. i just gave up and let it go ... filtering in the next pipeline stage works _all the time_ for me.

Comment: Understood, @Lee_Dailey - I've added more details on what does and doesn't work to the answer. I can definitely see why you would avoid these parameters, but perhaps spelling out all the "quirks" publicly here helps get them fixed, eventually.

Comment: @mklement0 - thank you for the added info. it helps make things a good bit more clear ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **`-Exclude` parameter**, which allows you to specify an *array* of exclusion wildcard patterns - **but see the caveats below**:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.xml, *.txt, *.log -Path $target_cis -Recurse -File | 
  Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

**Post-filtering solution**, building on your own attempt:

While it is generally preferable to solve a problem directly with a given cmdlet's parameter - both for concision and performance - as of PowerShell 7.2.2, there are good reasons to perform the filtering *separately*, applying it *after* `Get-ChildItem` has returned its (unfiltered) results (which is what you attempted):

- While `-Include` / `-Exclude` work as expected with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`, they don't without it, and it's not easy to remember this fact - see the bottom section.
- Combining `-Include` / `-Exclude` with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` is *unexpectedly slow* - even slower than a post-filtering solution: see [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662)

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path $target_cis -Recurse -File | 
  Where-Object { $_.Extension -notin '.xml', '.txt', '.log' } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

That is, switching from the `-ne` operator in your attempt (`$_.Extension -ne ".xml"`) to the 
[`-notin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) operator allows placing an *array* of strings on the RHS to test the the LHS string against:

`$_.Extension -notin '.xml', '.txt', '.log'`  returns `$true` if the value of `$_.Extension` is not present in the RHS array (using implicit `-eq` testing against each element).

---

**Caveats** as of PowerShell 7.2.2:

- **It is solely because your commands use `-Recurse` for recursive traversal with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) that `-Exclude` and `-Include` work as one would expect**; without `-Recurse`, these parameters exhibit counter-intuitive behavior - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).
- **With [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item), even `-Recurse` wouldn't make `-Include` work, though `-Exclude` would mostly work as expected**:

  - That is, while you *should* be able to use `-Include` with multiple wildcard patterns for inclusionary matching directly with `Copy-Item -Recurse` in order to limit what is copied to begin with, it doesn't work.
  - `-Include` is mistakenly applied to the *immediate target directory* and *only* to it:

    - If none of the specified patterns match *its* name, *nothing is copied*.
    - If any specified pattern *does* match its name, the *whole directory subtree* is copied *without filtering*.
  - `-Exclude`, by contrast, *mostly* works as expected: it applies the exclusion patterns on each level of the directory subtree hierarchy.

    - If any exclusion pattern happens to match the name of the *immediate target directory*, *nothing is copied*.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818635/45375) for a detailed discussion, including a problem with how `-Destination` arguments are interpreted.

Comment: Thanks, @WR7500; actually, `-Exclude` (mostly) does work as expected with `Copy-Item -Recurse`, but `-Include` is fundamentally broken - please see my update.