# Powershell Copy-Item not keeping folder structure

Tags: powershell

I have the below script to copy data from a local folder to a remote folder created with the current date. However the files are copying but the folder structure is not.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy"),$_.Extension
$Source = "E:\Folder1\\*"
$Dest   = "\\Server\Share\Folder2"
$Username = "Username"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
Remove-PSDrive -Name T
Start-Sleep -s 1
New-PSDrive -Name T -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Dest -Credential $mycreds -Persist
if (!(Test-Path "T:\$Date"))
{
    md -Path "T:\$Date"
}
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse | % { Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination "T:\$Date" -Container -Force -Verbose }
```

Could anyone advise where I am going wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nice script, I think we can get this sorted in no time!

#### Why this happened

The reason this is failing is in this step right here:

```
  Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse
```

The `-Recurse` switch is causing you pain.  To illustrate why this is, I created a simple folder structure.

[image]

When you run `Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse` alone, you'll get a recursive listing of all files in the `$Source` path, like so:

```
PS C:\temp\stack> Get-ChildItem -Recurse

Directory: C:\temp\stack

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/4/2017  10:50 AM                Source


Directory: C:\temp\stack\Source    

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/4/2017  10:57 AM                1
d-----         8/4/2017  10:57 AM                2
d-----         8/4/2017  10:57 AM                3
d-----         8/4/2017  10:57 AM                4


Directory: C:\temp\stack\Source\1    

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/4/2017  10:57 AM             20 Archive.rar
-a----         8/4/2017  10:56 AM              0 File01.bmp
```

Well, in the next step of your script, you pipe that output over to `Copy-Item` for every single file.

You're basically *expressly* telling PowerShell 'take this folder and all of it's subfolders and everything, and dump them all in this one folder, ignoring the folder structure'

#### How to fix

What you really want to do is simply move the `-Recurse` parameter over to `Copy-Item`, and you're done :)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source |  
    Copy-Item -Destination "T:\$Date" -Container -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Hope that helps, have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you for the advise FoxDeploy, when I move the -Recurse over I unfortunately see the following error: < The target file "T:\10312017 \folder" is a directory, not a file > and the copy fails.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few years old, but in case someone arrives here like I did...

[In another post, a user suggested using robocopy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67295837/6012415). It worked great for me:

```
robocopy "source/folder" "target/folder" "*.file_extension" /s
```

This command copies from the source folder the files that match the given filter, replicating the folder structure in the destination folder.

In this case, it would be used like:

```
robocopy "E:\Folder1\" "\\Server\Share\Folder2" "*" /s
```