# Powershell compress files older than X days from folder path by keeping folder structure (folder + sub-folders) and also exclude a few sub-folders

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, archive

I'm pretty new to Powershell in general, I've come across some partial solutions, but I can't find the right fit.
Ideally I would like to Archive (Zip) with Powershell but only files of a certain age (x days/months), but I would prefer keeping the folder structure and also add exclusions.
Here's what I've been trying to use (without success):

```
$inputFolder = "C:\Temp\Test"
$excludeFolders = @("\subfolderToKeep")
$ouputFileName="C:\Temp\archive.zip"
$Daysback = "-5"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)

$tempFolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
Remove-Item $tempFolder -Force
New-Item -Type  Directory -Path $tempFolder -Force
$exclude =@()
$excludeFolders | ForEach-Object {
 $exclude+=(Join-Path $inputFolder $_) 
 Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $inputFolder $_) -Recurse | 
  ForEach-Object{$exclude+=$_.FullName}}
Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notin $exclude -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } |
 Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $tempFolder $_.FullName.Substring($inputFolder.length)}

Get-ChildItem $tempFolder |
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ouputFileName -Update
```

The current setup would work without the date filtering:

> -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete

Comment: `$Daysback = "-5"` --> `$Daysback = -5`. No quotes, it's a (negative) int.

Comment: good catch, but still gives the same error as the temp folder can't match the $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete logical block

Comment: Try setting the date to midnight `$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback).Date`

Comment: it's not a date format matter rather the logic

Comment: `.Date` isn't formatting the datetime object, It merely sets the time part to 00:00:00 (midnight)

Comment: It runs with $_.LastWriteTime -gt $DatetoDelete ->but it simply can't take -lt

Comment: Then.. are you sure there are files in there with a LastWriteTime earlier than 5 days ago?

Comment: part of the problem is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383660/7787546

Comment: So you get an error message? Please add this in full to your question.