# How can I pipe multiple files into Copy-Item and keep the directory structure?

Tags: powershell

I have a very large directory located at `D:\Stuff` and I want to create a copy of it at `D:\CopyStuff`, but I only want to take files with a certain extension as well as keep the folder structure.

Getting the files I want seems simple enough:

```
$from = "D:\stuff"
$to = "D:\CopyStuff"   
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $from -Include *.config, *.txt, *.ini
```

However, copying the files and keeping the structure is a bit more challenging.  I *could* use a for-loop, but that seems against the very nature of Powershell.  Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25780745/782880, it suggests to do it this way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Container
```

But that copies files to `D:\CopyStuff` with no folders, much less my original structure.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Powershell 5.

Comment: while robocopy is FAR better at both copying AND moving files, the info you linked to has another link that says you need to use both `-Recurse` and `-Container:$False` to copy the Source dirtree to the Dest dirtree and preserve relative paths. ///// i have not tested it - i usually use robocopy - but the following post seems quite specific ... What is the meaning of Powershell's Copy-Item's -container argument? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129088/what-is-the-meaning-of-powershells-copy-items-container-argument ///// look at the highest voted answer. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$Source="C:\temp\test1"
$Dest="C:\temp\test2"
$EnableExt=".config", ".txt" , ".ini"

Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse | % {

    $NewPath=$_.FullName.Replace($Source, $Dest)

    if ($_.psiscontainer)
    {
        New-Item -Path $NewPath -ItemType Directory -Force
    }
    elseif ($_.Extension -in $EnableExt)
    {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName $NewPath -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Copy-Item` can do it on its own like:

```
$fromFolder = "C:\Temp\Source"
$toFolder = "C:\Temp\Dest"
Copy-Item -Path $fromFolder -Destination $toFolder -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```

But, you may not like the result: it will make folder "Source" inside the "Dest" folder, and then copy the structure. I reckon, you need the same files/folders from inside "Source" folder to be copy to the "Dest" folder. Well, it's a bit more complex, but here it is:

```
$fromFolder = "C:\Temp\Source"
$toFolder = "C:\Temp\Dest"

Get-ChildItem -Path $fromFolder -Directory -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, @{N="NewPath";E={$_.FullName.Replace($fromFolder, $toFolder)}} | ForEach-Object { New-Item -Path $_.NewPath -ItemType "Directory" }
Get-ChildItem -Path $fromFolder -Include "*.txt" -Recurse | Select-Object FullName, @{N="NewPath";E={$_.FullName.Replace($fromFolder, $toFolder)}} | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.NewPath }
```

It copies folder structure first, then files.

**NB!** I do strongly recommend to use absolute paths only. Otherwise, the `Replace` method may give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The solution below creates analogous target folders only for those source folders that contain files matching the `-Include` filter, not for *all* source folders.

---

You can get away with a single-pipeline solution by combining [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-Name` with [delay-bind script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters):

```
$from = 'D:\stuff'
$to = 'D:\CopyStuff'

Get-ChildItem -Name -Recurse -LiteralPath $from -Include *.config, *.txt, *.ini |
  Copy-Item `
    -LiteralPath { Join-Path $from $_ } `
    -Destination { New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Split-Path (Join-Path $to $_)) }
```

- `-Name` emits paths *relative* to the input directory as strings.
- Delay-bind script block `{ Join-Path $from $_ }` builds the *full* input file name from each relative input path.
- Delay-bind script block `{ New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Split-Path (Join-Path $to $_)) }` builds the full path of the target *directory* from the target root path and the relative input path and creates that directory on demand, using a preexisting one if present (`-Force`).